# Connecting MISO and MOSI signals between master and slave

Tags: pcb-design, embedded, flash, hardware

My goal is to flash the external SPI of ICE40 FPGA through Dediprog before powering on the FPGA and let the FPGA read the image file in the SPI after powering on the FPGA.

after trying doing this on the [iCE40 16-WLCSP Evaluation Kit](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dbaa0ar5x4560m/ICE40-16-WLCSP-Eval-Kit-Guide.pdf?dl=0), the FPGA was able to read the image when J25 was connected on the horizontal jumpers (see schematic in the pdf):

[image]

I wanted to make sure that I understand this connection.
the way I understand it, connecting 3 to 1, and 4 to 2 means that the ICE FPGA is the master and the Flash is the Slave.
and connecting 1 to 2 and 3 to 4 is the opposite.

although in other designs, I saw that the right connection was MOSI on the "DI" input in the flash, and MISO to the "DO" output in the flash. here it appears that they flipped MISO and MOSI, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signals are connected like this when the jumper is in the horizontal position:

`IOB_44_SDO (FPGA) -> ice_SO -> sensor3_flsh_mosi -> SDI (flash)`

`IOB_45_SDI (FPGA) -> ice_SI -> sensor3_flsh_miso -> SDO (flash)`

So in the end, it's all connected just as you expected. The "MOSI" (master out, slave in) signal is connected to "SDO" on the FPGA, meaning that the FPGA is the master. It is also connected to "SDI" on the flash, meaning that the flash is a slave device.

When you flip the jumpers into the vertical position, SDO of the flash is connected to SDO of the FPGA. The same happens with SDI. This means that when the jumpers are vertical, both the FPGA and the flash are slave devices. (The FT2232HL is the master in that case.)